# create div for each createelement, javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create div in javascript for each create elements(DOM) and retrieve their values?

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute("id", "x" + i);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "div"+i;}
```

Comment: Please try to write your question more clearly.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery? http://jquery.com/ jQuery makes it very easy to manipulate HTML

Comment: I've write create element in javascript function and I want to create div for each of them.

Comment: How can I create new element in new div I created?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to append all of your inputs into your divs and then your divs into the body.

Use the function [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), which is available on all DOM nodes, furthermore, your code will not work since `inputVN` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this
document.body.appendChild(element);
example for create a div with javascript

```
var Div = document.createElement('div');
        Div.id = 'DivId';
        document.body.appendChild(Div);
```

this is a little example how create  a div, you can try with these